# Spark dataframe - Split struct column into 2 columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

## Context

I have a data frame containing *(what I think are)* couples of `(String, String)`.

It looks like this:

```
> df.show
| Col1 | Col2    |
| A    | [k1, v1]|
| A    | [k2, v2]|

> df.printSchema
|-- _1: string (nullable = true)
|-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

`Col2` used to contain a `Map[String, String]` on which I have done a `toList()` and then `explode()` to obtain one row per mapping present in the original Map.

## Question

I would like to split `Col2` into 2 columns and obtain this dataframe:

```
| Col1 | key    | value |
| A    | k1     | v1    |
| A    | k2     | v2    |
```

**Does anyone know how to do this?**

**Alternatively, Does anyone know how to explode+split a map into multiple rows (one per mapping) and 2 columns (one for key, one for value).**

## Thing I have tried / Error

I tried using the usually successful pattern with `(String, String)` but this does not work:

```
df.select("Col1", "Col2").
   map(r =>(r(0).asInstanceOf[String],
            r(1).asInstanceOf[(String, String)](0),
            r(1).asInstanceOf[(String, String)](1)
           )
       )

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to scala.Tuple2
```

==> I guess the type of Col2 is `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema`, could not find  spark / scala doc for this.

And even if that worked, there would then be the issue that using indexes is not the right way to access elements of a tuple...

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use select to project each element of struct to unpack it.

```
df.select($"Col1", $"Col2._1".as("key"), $"Col2._2".as("value"))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just add another method to do that:

```
df.withColumn("key", $"Col2._1")
  .withColumn("value", $"Col2._2")
```