# How can I split a column containing array of some struct into separate columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have the following scenarios:

```scala
case class attribute(key:String,value:String)
case class entity(id:String,attr:List[attribute])


val entities = List(entity("1",List(attribute("name","sasha"),attribute("home","del"))),
entity("2",List(attribute("home","hyd"))))

val df = entities.toDF()

// df.show
+---+--------------------+
| id|                attr|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|[[name,sasha], [d...|
|  2|        [[home,hyd]]|
+---+--------------------+

//df.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- attr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
      |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

what I want to produce is

```
+---+--------------------+-------+
| id|  name              |  home |
+---+--------------------+-------+
|  1| sasha              |del    |
|  2| null               |hyd    |
+---+--------------------+-------+
```

How do I go about this. I looked at quite a few similar questions on stack but couldn't find anything useful.

My main motive is to do groupBy on different attributes, thus want to bring it in the above mentioned format.

I looked into explode functionality. It breaks downs a list in separate rows, I don't want that. I want to create more columns from the array of `attribute`.

Similar things I found:

[Spark - convert Map to a single-row DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49386299/spark-convert-map-to-a-single-row-dataframe)

[Split 1 column into 3 columns in spark scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255973/split-1-column-into-3-columns-in-spark-scala)

[Spark dataframe - Split struct column into 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49440618/spark-dataframe-split-struct-column-into-2-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can easily be reduced to [PySpark converting a column of type 'map' to multiple columns in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36869134) or [How to get keys and values from MapType column in SparkSQL DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40602606/10938362). First convert `attr` to `map<string, string>`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode, map_from_entries, map_keys}

val dfMap = df.withColumn("attr", map_from_entries($"attr"))
```

then it's just a matter of finding the unique keys

```
val keys = dfMap.select(explode(map_keys($"attr"))).as[String].distinct.collect
```

then selecting from the map

```
val result = dfMap.select($"id" +: keys.map(key => $"attr"(key) as key): _*)
result.show
```

```
+---+-----+----+
| id| name|home|
+---+-----+----+
|  1|sasha| del|
|  2| null| hyd|
+---+-----+----+
```

Less efficient but more concise variant is to `explode` and `pivot`

```
val result = df
  .select($"id", explode(map_from_entries($"attr")))
  .groupBy($"id")
  .pivot($"key")
  .agg(first($"value"))

result.show
```

```
+---+----+-----+
| id|home| name|
+---+----+-----+
|  1| del|sasha|
|  2| hyd| null|
+---+----+-----+
```

but in practice I'd advise against it.

Comment: used udf from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109247/spark-scala-dataframe-convert-a-column-of-array-of-struct-to-a-column-of-map instead of map_from_entries. Thanks alot.